# Django class based views example

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I can't understand the class based views, so I am trying to figure it out with an example. Here is what I have so far:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^(?P<langcode>[a-zA-Z-]+/about/$', about, name='about')


#views.py
def about(request, langcode):
    languages = Language.objects.values_list('code', flat=True)
    language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=langcode)
    return render(request, 'about.html', {
        'languages': languages,
        'language': language
    })
```

I also have some other functional views which contain the first 2 lines of `about`:

```
languages = Language.objects.values_list('code', flat=True)
language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=langcode)
```

So, what I want to do now is:

1. create a `class BaseView` (or however you want to call it) which extends
   something from `django.generic.views` and which will determine the `language` and `languages` parameters for the context based on the `langcode` input parameter
2. Create the `class AboutView(BaseView)` (so extending the `BaseView`) which will somehow define the template name `about.html` to be used for rendering.
3. I will further have another class based view, also to extend `BaseView` and which is simillar to `AboutView`, but which sets one more context parameter called `region` depending as well on the `langcode` input parameter

Can someone show me exactly how to code this stuff? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to achieve what you want:

You first define the common logic, using the TemplateView generic view:

```
class MyBaseView(TemplateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # dispatch takes care of "reading" the parameters from the url
        self.language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=kwargs.pop("langcode")) # I would use some kind of default value to prevent exception, but its up to your logic
        return TemplateView.dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # get_context_data creates the context
        context = TemplateView.get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        context.update({"language": self.language, 
                        "languages": Language.objects.values_list('code', flat=True)})

        return context
```

Then, you don't even need an AboutView because all you want is to control the template_name, so in your urls.py:

```
# in urls,py you can just use this, instead of defining an AboutView, you pass the template_name you want to use, this is sufficient because TemplateView expects a template_name attribute
url('^(?P<langcode>[a-zA-Z]+)/about/$', MyBaseView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name='about')
```

and finally, for the other view that uses `region` you can just inherit from the MyBaseView, and add the context you want:

```
class AboutViewWithRegion(MyBaseView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = MyBaseView.get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        context.update({"region": <<your logic here>>})
        return context
```

Hope that helps!